# How to remove our IP address from Microsoft's email blacklist?

Tags: email, ip-address, microsoft, blacklist, hotmail

We have a website, users sign up and receive links to confirm they signed up BUT:

1. Microsoft blocked our IP (no one with Microsoft email account can receive our emails.)
2. We tried contacting microsoft submitting the detailed form about our problem.
3. We posted 3 times in their community about our problem.
4. We tweeted they about our problem.
5. We tried finding out some telephone support number (the few there are aren't helping at all.)

Do you think we solved?  the answer is **NO** :/

We are still unable to send emails from our IP to [Microsoft](http://microsoft.com) email accounts and have been unable to for the last 3 months.

Our emails are perfect.  We checked all the email headers following Microsoft's guidelines, but it seems not enough.  Checking our IP reputation it seems everything is OK, indeed we can send email easly to any other provider: Gmail, Yahoo, etc.

Here is the full error returned by Microsoft:

```
host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120] said: 550
    SC-001 (COL0-MC4-F28) Unfortunately, messages from 94.23.***** weren't
    sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their
    network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to
    http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL
    FROM command)
```

We are running NGIX + PHP mailer from a virtual private server (no Hosting or shared hosting.)

Are there any other way to try to get help?

Comment: Is this the form that you filled out?  https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts&wa=wsignin1.0&scrx=1

Comment: @StephenOstermiller nope :) it was another one i don't remember the link is that relevant? i submitted 4 times :/

Comment: That was the one that I found recommended in this Microsoft help forum: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-email/why-are-the-emails-sent-to-microsoft-account/b64e3e4a-0d93-40c8-8e28-4be849012f9c

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  yeah, it's unbelievable, the form i found was another one probably the latest version of that, i submitted 4 times but no one submit returned a confirm message :/ like the form was broken  unbelievable, billionaire companies not able to build a simple submission form with a confirm message , unbelievable :/

Comment: I guess they are now big enough to start making everyone crazy, simply by not following the rules. Many people told me "hey, they are Microsoft, they must be right", but then I explain them and they see where the problem is. So now I simply tell the people who are blocked by Microsoft: call the recipient who you can't send mail to, they should call Microsoft to unblock you. Because they are Microsoft customers, then Microsoft must react. That's the only reasonable way to solve this issue.

Comment: Your IP address may not be blocked in some cases, but your email could be blocked by their SmartScreen filter, that's not so smart :-).

Comment: check symantec ipremoval list, http://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/lookup/ for me nothing answered except requesting there, they answer for 24 hours after request but for me it was less than 1 hour!

Comment: Just wanted to add if you are using a service such as Mailgun, contact them - it could be someone else on the server that is causing issues and causing a ban.

Answer (score 16):

I have had server IP's blacklisted by Microsoft a few times and I have had them removed reasonably quickly. I noticed that after entering and joining anti spam related services that they recommend it was faster and easier.

I recommend that you ensure that you can reply Yes to the below questions (except the last one) in the web form where you ask for support for quickest removal.

- Are you currently a Return Path client?
- Are you Sender Score Certified?
- Do you publish Sender Policy Framework (SPF)/Sender ID records for your IP?
- Are you in the Junk Mail Reporting Partner Program?
- Do you use Smart Network Data Services?
- Is your IP from a "bad range"? Microsoft has penalties for some ranges they consider untrusted. You will need to request whitelisting.

Here is the link to the webform I have used in the past with success: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635611717755428181

I truly recommend that you read this and follow the recommendations:

https://mail.live.com/mail/services.aspx

Comment: This didn't work for me, after using the form I got the following email: `Dear [my name], Please note that your ticket number is in the subject line of this mail. [the IP I entered] Note: Errors are unlikely, however, if an error is indicated, please resubmit the specific IP or IP range. Thank you, Outlook.com Deliverability Support`. What does that mean? The only contents of this email is the IP I entered, there are no sentences in this email. Does this mean that I should fill out the form again? If so, why? It looks like they didn't finish programming this response email template...

Comment: It turns out that the above email seems to be a very poorly worded "we have received your message" email. I have now received a second email saying that the problem was `conditionally mitigated`.

Comment: Here's the working link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635611717755428181

Answer (score 3):

Go to the below URL and search on for your domain.

> http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

This will check a bunch of blacklists and it will tell you if your domain is listed. there is also advise on how to get removed.

You might be listed with more than just Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft keeps their own blacklist and will block you even if mxtoolbox reports you perfectly clean.